# Ignore specific file Xdebug Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm using Xdebug as my debugger for my code. Although adminer errors all the time (probably because of the obfuscation of the source code.)

I now want to ignore that specific file, and found that you can ignore folders, but don't see any option to ignore a specific file.

This is how to ignore a specific folder:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000,
        "ignore": [
            "**/vendor/**/*"
          ]
    }
```

Now, logically thinking I thought I'd change `"**/vendor/**/*"` to `adminer.php`. But that didn't work. I also tried changing it to `*adminer.php` and `*/adminer.php` but this doesn't work as well.

Is there a possibility for doing this?

I need it to be able to have this specific different, so not in any config file of Xdebug itself, but in launch.json

Comment: Have you tried **/adminer.php

Answer (score 3):

Recent VSCODE (**Debug by XDEBUG extension**) does not recognize `"ignore"` key (neither `"exclude"`) to skip PHP debugging, instead it supports:

```
"skipFiles": [
    "**/vendor/dir/to/yourfile.php",
]
```

*(other valid answers stated this too, but unfortunately there were deleted for some reason)*

Comment: I get a `Property skipFiles is not allowed.` warning when adding that. Is there anything else needed to make it work? I've read elsewhere that it only works for Node.

Comment: I guess it depends on which extension you're using, `PHP Debug by Xdebug` [supports](https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug) `skipFiles` and `ignore`. `PHP by Devsense` [supports](https://github.com/DEVSENSE/phptools-docs/blob/d8cde349692f3b8058363727b968593d285d5000/docs/vscode/Debug/launch-json.md#ignored-paths) `excluded`.

Comment: I have been searching for this for a long time. Thanks a lot.